# How to write rspec for rails jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

Hi i am working with a RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and rails 5. I am using AWS SQS. I have created a job as follows:-

```
class ReceiptsProcessingJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as 'abc'

  def perform(receipt_id)
    StoreParserInteractor.process_reciept(receipt_id)
  end
end
```

Now i want to write unit test for it. I tried like:-

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

describe ReceiptsProcessingJob do

  describe "#perform_later" do
    it "scan a receipt" do
      ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
      expect {
        ReceiptsProcessingJob.perform_later(1)
      }.to have_enqueued_job
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesnot cover `StoreParserInteractor.process_reciept(receipt_id)`. Please help how can i cover this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The example is testing the job class. You need to write a spec for `StoreParserInteractor` and test the method `process_reciept`.

Something along the lines of (pseudo code):

```
describe StoreParserInteractor do
  describe "#process_receipt" do
    it "does that" do
      result = StoreParserInteractor.process_receipt(your_data_here)
      expect(result to be something)...
    end
  end
end
```

But, the Rails guide suggests this kind of test:

```
assert_enqueued_with(job: ReceiptsProcessingJob) do
  StoreParserInteractor.process_reciept(receipt_id)
end
```

Maybe this increases code coverage as well.

Comment: Thanks but i have already write a spec for StoreParserInteractor and test for process_reciept. this file has covered the 100%.

Comment: @awsmsid can you also provide the output of the coverage tool, and the implementation of the StoreParserInteractor class?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't actually test the `ActiveJob` itself, but the logic behind it.

You should write a test for `StoreParserInteractor#process_reciept`. Think of `ActiveJob` as an "external framework" and it is not your responsibility to test the internals of it (e.g. if the job was enqueued or not).

As **kitschmaster** said, don't test ActiveJob classes, in short

Comment: If i do not test for ActiveJob still it shows the coverage for ActiveJob is 75%. i have wrote the test for  StoreParserInteractor#process_reciept still its not working.

Comment: You can remove ActiveJob from the coverage

Comment: I don't want to remove it.

Comment: Looks like ReceiptsProcessingJob.perform_later(receipt.id) i havenot covered this line. i have used the  allow(ReceiptsProcessingJob)
        .to receive(:perform_later).with(any_args) { receipt_with_max_size }

Comment: I also try like expect(StoreParserInteractor).to receive(:process_receipt).with(receipt_id) but i am getting an error 
expected: 1 time with arguments: (3) 
received: 0 times